# Python: take log difference for each column in a dataframe

Tags: python, logarithm

I have a list of dataframes and would like to take log for every element in these dataframes and find the first difference. In time series econometrics, this procedure gives an approximate growth rate. The following codes

```
for i in [0, 1, 2, 5]:
    df1_list[i] = 100 * np.log(df_list[i]).diff()
```

gives an error

```
__main__:7: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
__main__:7: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
```

When I look at the result, many of the elements resulting dataframes are nan. How can I fix the codes? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your code, but with your data. You do not get an error but two warnings. The most likely reasons are the following kinds of values within your DataFrames:

1. Zeros
2. Negative numbers
3. Non-numerical values

The logarithm of any of these is just not defined, so you get `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Some test data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5))
df = df.mask(np.random.random(df.shape) < .1)
```

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.579643  0.614592  0.333945  0.241791  0.426162
1  0.576076  0.841264  0.235148  0.577707  0.278260
2  0.735097  0.594789  0.640693  0.913639  0.620021
3  0.015446       NaN  0.062203  0.253076  0.042025
4  0.401775  0.522634  0.521139  0.032310       NaN
```

Applying your code

```
for c in df:
    print(100 * np.log(df[c]).diff())
```

yields output like this (for `c = 1`):

```
0          NaN
1    31.394708
2   -34.670002
3          NaN
4          NaN
```

You can remove `nans` with `.dropna()`

```
for c in df:
    print(100 * np.log(df[c].dropna()).diff())
```

which yields (for `c = 1`)

```
0          NaN
1    31.394708
2   -34.670002
4   -12.932474
```

As you can see, we have "lost" one row as a consequence of `.dropna()` and your 0th row will always be `nan` as there is no difference to take.

If you are interested in **replacing** nans with other values, there are different techniques such as [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or [imputation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html).